# Raspberry Pi 4 B I2C is enabled but does not work

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-4, i2c, software-installation

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 B and I'm trying to set up in I2C Connection with an MCP23018-E/SP I/O-Port-Expander via GPIO02 and GPIO03. I have **enabled I2c** on the Raspi by:

- adding:      dtparam=i2c1=on     to    /boot/config.txt

  ```
          dtparam=i2s=on      to    /boot/config.txt

          dtparam=i2c_arm=on  to    /boot/config.txt 

          dtoverlay=i2c1,pin2_3(tried it as well without the last three)
  ```
- added all modules in /etc/modules
- enabled automatic load of i2c kernel at boot
- installed i2c-tools, python-smbus.

for
$ ls -l /dev/i2c-*
I get:
**crw-rw--- 1 root i2c 89, 0 Okt 05 18:00 /dev/i2c-1**

So my bus should be set up correctly.
I know, you have to use the alternative functions for the GPIO Pins to get I2C, so I set:

- raspi-gpio set 02 a0
- raspi-gpio set 03 a0 (because SDA1/SCL1 are Alternate functions for GPIO 02 and GPIO 03. I get as well for raspi-gpio get 02,03 **that the SDA/SCL are enabled**.

I tried it aswell for different Pins, whose alternate function can provide an i2c buses, but none of them show a result for
i2cdetect -y 1

I looked at the channels with an oscilloscope, and from my point of view, the Raspi is **NOT** sending SDA and SCL, there are both just high at 3,3 V.

I really tried everything to send the I2C signals, but it will not work and I don't have a different device to check my circuit, but I'm pretty sure on the hardware side everything is correctly wired.

Any help would be really helpful.

PJ_2810

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you have configured is not needed and may be part of the problem.

Don't add modules to /etc/modules, don't set the GPIO mode with raspi-gpio or similar, don't enable automatic load of I2C kernel at boot.

Remove everything you have done and just add the following line to `/boot/config.txt`.

`dtparam=i2c_arm=on`

Reboot and check that the device `/dev/i2c-1` exists.  If it does you are ready to go.

Comment: And if it doesn't?